# Neo4j MATCH then MERGE too many DB hits

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, property-graph

This is the query:

```
MATCH (n:Client{curp:'SOME_VALUE'}) 
WITH n 
MATCH (n)-[:HIZO]-()-[r:FB]-()-[:HIZO]-(m:Client) 
WHERE ID(n)<>ID(m)
AND NOT (m)-[:FB]->(n) 
MERGE (n)-[:FB]->(m) RETURN m.curp
```

[image: PROFILE]

Why is the Merge stage getting so many DB hits if the query already narrowed down
n, m pairs to 6,781 rows?

Details of that stage shows this:

```
n, m, r
(n)-[ UNNAMED155:FB]->(m)
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a challenge for the optimizer, but what's the point of the first `WITH`? You could use `MATCH (n:Client{curp:'SOME_VALUE'})-[:HIZO]-()-[r:FB]-()-[:HIZO]-(m:Client)`

Comment: Tried changing it, but it does not make any difference on the merge

Comment: Have you tried removing the r variable from your pattern (you never use it, so you don't need it), and adding `WITH DISTINCT n, m` before your MERGE?

Comment: @InverseFalcon the distinct helped a lot from, 36 seconds to 7.
Only 81 rows after that. The MERGE stage still has 482,923 db hits (Down from 60M) why is it so expensive if we already narrowed down to 81 pairs?
thanks

Comment: Honestly I'm scratching my head about that too. Keep in mind that MERGE isn't a single operation, it attempts a MATCH first, and if no match is found, it will do a CREATE. Because of your previous WHERE clause, you should be able to use CREATE instead of MERGE. I'm summarizing all this in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that queries build up rows, and operations in your query get run on every row that is built up.

Because the pattern in your match may find multiple paths to the same :Client, it will build up multiple rows with the same n and m (but possibly different r, but as you aren't using r anywhere else in your query, I encourage you to remove the variable).

This means that even though you mean to MERGE a single relationship between n and a distinct m, this MERGE operation will actually be run for every single duplicate row of n and m. One of those MERGEs will create the relationship, the others will be wasting cycles matching on the relationship that was created without doing anything more.

That's why we should be able to lower our db hits by only considering distinct pairs of n and m before doing the MERGE.

Also, since your query made sure we're only considering n and m where the relationship doesn't exist, we can safely use CREATE instead of MERGE, and it should save us some db hits because MERGE always attempts a MATCH first, which isn't necessary.

An improved query might look like this:

```
MATCH (n:Client{curp:'SOME_VALUE'}) 
WITH n 
MATCH (n)-[:HIZO]-()-[:FB]-()-[:HIZO]-(m:Client) 
WHERE n <> m
AND NOT (m)-[:FB]->(n) 
WITH DISTINCT n, m
MERGE (n)-[:FB]->(m) 
RETURN m.curp
```

EDIT

Returning the query to use MERGE for the :FB relationship, as attempts to use CREATE instead ended up not being as performant.

Comment: Thanks, as some commenter above also suggested, adding the DISTINCT does lower the hits a lot. However im not sure the CREATE is a good idea since it will start producing duplicates every time I run this query.
The MERGE stage still has 482,923 db hits (Down from 60M). As I understand MERGE will first try to match and then if the pattern is not present, create it. I think that 482,923 is still a lot considering both ends of the relationship are already bound, Is there anyway to speed this up? or to look inside the MERGE to see what it is doing? Thanks

Comment: Actually I didn't read correctly. You are saying that since im already checking that the relationship does not exists it is safe to use CREATE, However im checking for NOT (m)-[:FB]->(n)  and creating (n)-[:FB]->(m) **the reverse direction**. I think the original intent was to make the connection only if there was not a previous connection in any direction, so the NOT filter checks one direction and the MERGE the other one... but I guess i could just check for any direction in the filter and use CREATE, right?

Comment: Exactly, I had misread the direction initially, and just updated my answer with the solution you proposed.

Comment: When using that filter the time went up to 35 secs, again. (I guess now the filter is checking a lot of duplicates) So far the DISTINCT and merge are the best.

Comment: Sounds good, always helpful to run those comparisons. I reset my query back to using MERGE.

Comment: Thanks, I ve reading a bit more and I think that is as good as it gets, it is a MERGE(Into) (similar to EXPAND(Into)? and I think that is optimal), so it knows both ends, I guess they just have too many edges.